# Controling Edit, Delete on individual items

Tags: asp.net-dynamic-data

Is there a way to enale/disable the edit and delete on individual entity instances using a propery on the entity when displaying in the List control?

Answer (score 0):

H Marius, I have a security sample that uses routing to do this sort of thing, what is it exactly you are trying to do achive?

Comment: Cool, I found your article and it was exactly what I needed.